# Signature could not be verified for kubernetes repo

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, yum

Tring to install kubernetes cluster with kubeadm, and faced issue with installing kube packages.
I continue getting error:

```
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes
```

Repo config:

```
    [kubernetes]
    name=Kubernetes
    baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
    enabled=1
    gpgcheck=1
    repo_gpgcheck=1
    gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
    exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Im using centos 7 distro

```
Linux kube-master 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 18:28:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see very similar issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60134).

As a **quick workaround**, you can simply disable **GPG checking** by setting `repo_gpgcheck=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo` but this is obviously not recommended from security perspective.

Additionally you may try the following:

- re-import the keys as suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60134#issuecomment-385942005)

  ```
  rpm --import https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
  ```
- install the following version of **GNUPG** as suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60134#issuecomment-573247871)

  ```
  sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64.rpm
  ```